# Sign-in with Google disabled for even the simplest script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I noticed one of my scripts stopped working and was trying to debug. I couldn't get anything to work. So I created a totally blank spreadsheet and a new script and I am still getting this error:

[image: Sign-in with Google temporarily disabled for this app]

I am not sure where to go from here. I found a way to request verification for a project, however, I want to ask other first to figure out what is going on. Is there a quota that I have missed?

Comment: Have you tried using Chrome in incognito mode? I don't think that there is quota that will cause that message. Have you published an addon? Are you using a regular Google account or a G Suite account?

Comment: This is an unpublished script on a commercial account. On my business account I can still run scripts with no problem. Even in incognito account when I log into my commercial account it won't run the script. When I remove the call to the SpreadsheetApp methods however, it will run. I just can't run anything that requires authenticating the script.

Comment: There is [a conversation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-apps-script-community/NL071uBevw4/C2uMkNSDBgAJ) on the official Google Apps Script community about this. Not a clear description of what is causing this situation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your Google regular/commercial account reached a quota

From [OAuth API Verification FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914)

> **Users seeing the Unverified App Screen or "Sign-in with Google temporarily disabled"**
>
> Why are users seeing this?
> To protect users and Google systems from abuse, unverified apps that are accessing restricted or sensitive scopes have a 100-user quota restriction. Failure to get your app verified before making requests to sensitive or restricted scopes will result in your project's 100-user quota eventually getting exhausted and Google sign-in being disabled for your users. Learn more about [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=es).